# robotium and android annotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm trying to test an activity including annotations from android-annotations 2.7 like @EActivity, @ViewById, etc. Every test fails because of an NoClassDefFoundError. Has anyone a working example how to combine Robotium with Android Annotations?
Here's my test case:

```
package de.abc.view;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

import de.abc.R;

public class WorktimeActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<WorktimeActivity_>{

    private Solo solo;

    public WorktimeActivityTest() {
        super(WorktimeActivity_.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testSelectWorkday() {
        Button button = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.selectWorkday);
        solo.clickOnView(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }


}
```

Comment: which call it couldn't find?

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076694/classnotfoundexception-using-androidannotations

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake. The class that couldn't be found wasn't included in the build path. So I had to change my build path and include the generated sources from android-annotations...stupid mistake...